# Can anyone help me to write a query so that I can get How much space occupied by a database per month and year wise in sql server

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone help me to write a query so that I can get How much space occupied by a database per month and year wise in sqlserver.

I have tried :

```
   SELECT sys.databases.name,CONVERT(VARCHAR,SUM(size)*8/1024)+' MB' AS [Totaldisk space]
   FROM sys.databases 
   JOIN sys.master_files
   ON sys.databases.database_id=sys.master_files.database_id
   GROUP BY sys.databases.name
   ORDER BY sys.databases.name
```

But How do I get how much space occupied by each database in year and month wise

Comment: Size per database can only be present, can't retrieve past sizes. Make sure to save this info from now on or enable tracing.

Comment: If you didn't store the information on how large your database was this time last year, there's only one way to get it; use a Time Machine. If you need this data, and previously weren't storing it, you have no way of getting it. if you need it going forward, start storing the information regularly, and then in a months/years time you can at least access that information from today onwards.

Answer (score 0):

[DBWarden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Monitoring/98106/)

Is a free open source tool that can track and save this for you. Follow the link to find out how it can help you. I have no connection to it except as a happy user.

You can even copy the relevant procs and use them to suit your environment if you don't want the whole thing on your server. All the code is there.